# Modify background image size using html

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div style="container;background-image:url('/images/football.jpg');background-size:100% 100%;">
```

I would like to manually adjust the width and height of the image. I currently have it covering the full width of the div, but not the full height. Is there a way to manually adjust the size in percentage form while maintaining no-repeat of image.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned 
      "background-size:"
Is what you are after however I thought I'd just add a little bit of helpful advice and point you towards W3schools.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

I only recently got through web development at Uni and W3schools was the single most useful source of information I had access to (don't tell my lecturer that). If you get in the habit of looking there first it'll help you out a bunch.

Also might be worth learning how to use external style sheets and linking them into your HTML.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100%;
```

will adjust the image proportionally to 100% width of the background area.

If your image size is less then background area then use

```
background-size:cover;
```

to stretch it so that the background area is completely covered by the background image.

If your image size is greator then background area then use

```
 background-size:contain;
```

to shrink it so that the background image is completely fit in the background area.